# Best_in_place gem, does not display text for dropdowns

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1, best-in-place

I am using https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place gem to edit form fields in place

**Seems like the current value is shown as '-' when using collections.**
[image]

However on-click the dropdown has the current values:
[image]

```
Here is the code I am using:


      %tr
        %td  #{best_in_place sku.product, :name, as: :select, :class=>"best_in_place", collection: Product.all.map { |i| [i.id, i.name]}}
        %td #{sku.size}
        %td #{sku.kind}
```

Looking closer, The value that the best_in_place method generates seems to be missing the "String (Product name)" between spans

```
pry(#<#<Class:0x007fb155848308>>)> best_in_place sku.product, :name, as: :select, :class=>"best_in_place", collection: Product.all.map { |i| [i.id, i.name]}
  Product Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products"  WHERE "products"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
  Product Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products"
=> "<span class=\"best_in_place best_in_place\" data-bip-attribute=\"name\" data-bip-collection=\"[[1,&quot;Milk&quot;],[2,&quot;Water&quot;],[3,&quot;Bread&quot;],[4,&quot;Eggs&quot;],[6,&quot;Yogurt&quot;],[8,&quot;Dogfood&quot;],[5,&quot;Cereal&quot;],[9,&quot;Oatmeal&quot;],[10,&quot;Soda&quot;],[11,&quot;Paper Towels&quot;],[12,&quot;Toilet Paper&quot;],[7,&quot;Coffee Beans&quot;]]\" data-bip-object=\"product\" data-bip-original-content=\"Eggs\" data-bip-skip-blur=\"false\" data-bip-type=\"select\" data-bip-url=\"/products/4\" data-bip-value=\"Eggs\" id=\"best_in_place_product_4_name\">**</span>**"
```

I am trying to poke around the code for the gem to see if this is a bug, but anyone knows if I am doing something wrong with the way I am using it?

**Update**

I replaced sku.product with @user (just to test out if the issue with the model) and it displays correct option from the Product names (Milk).

```
      %tr
        %td  #{best_in_place @user, :phone, as: :select, :class=>"best_in_place", collection: Product.all.map { |i| [i.id, i.name]}}
        %td #{sku.size}
        %td #{sku.kind}
```

I am wondering it wont let me use a dropdown for Product names when using the Product model because the name column is a string field and not a numeric so it cant save that in the db through dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a hash of options where the keys and values are the same worked.

Check this for more details:

[Rails 4 Best in place select collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27569811/rails-4-best-in-place-select-collection)

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:
`= best_in_place other_expense, :currency, as: :select, collection: {'RUR' => 'RUR', 'EUR' => 'EUR', 'USD' => 'USD'}`