# how to display current value in select field with using rails gem best_in_place?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I am using rails gem best_in_place.

In select field it doesn't display the current value, instead it displays something like `-`.

Also, the date field doesn't change date if I select other data.

```
<% @user.each do |record| %>    
 <tr>
  <td>
     <%= best_in_place record, :name, :as => :input %> 
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= best_in_place record, :gender, :as => :select, collection: (MUser.pluck(:id, :gender)) %>
  </td>
   <%= best_in_place record, :dob, :as => :date, class: 'datepicker1 %>
  </td>
 </tr>
<% end %>
```

for datepicker used gem datepicker.
Datepicker configuration:

```
$('.datepicker1').datepicker({      
    regional: "en",
    todayHighlight: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    language: "en",
    orientation: "auto",
    toggleActive: true,
    autoclose: true
});
```

first time Onload page date field:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKhwU.png)
this image is default view when 1st time page load.

2. when i click on that field then opened datpicker and selected, but date is selected like `05/16/1923`.
   and as i set in datepicker js, not working like configured way.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdqXc.png)

Comment: does your server receive a request? What's the result? I don't know about best_in_place, but it looks like a) your `dob` is not initialized with any value and b) it's not updated

Comment: @Geoffroy Sir, I am displaying this user's data on indesx datatable screen, and trying update using rails gem `best_in_place` like inline update.

Comment: you still need a controller action to do the update for you

Comment: @Geoffroy sir,  i have update action in controller and also updated text box values, but having issue in select field and date field didn't displyed old value in the place.

Comment: @vvp45 - can you please tell me the datatype of `gender` field. I believe it's string.

Comment: yes it's string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the collection of `gender` like `[['Male', 'Male'], ['Female', 'Female']]` instead of the collection of `id` and `gender` like `[[1, 'Male'], [2, 'Female']]`. It will display the current value if the collection is right.

Check with this code

```
<%= best_in_place record, :gender, :as => :select, collection: [['Male', 'Male'], ['Female', 'Female']] %>
```

Don't know why you want to collect gender from `MUser`. Still want to use `MUser` then try this.

```
<%= best_in_place record, :gender, :as => :select, collection: MUser.pluck(:gender).uniq.map { |g| Array.new(2, g) } %>
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: It's need cause, now it's for one select field, i am using in future select fields.

Comment: i have already tried both soluntion, select filed option displayed when clicked on this select field. even not displayed current value. displayed like `-` on load page.

Comment: @wp45 To make it work I had to use a Hash as shown in my response. Did you try it ? it works for me.

Comment: yes, it's work, even onclick displayed select options, but on page load current value not displayed.

Comment: @Nitin Srivastava Sir, having issue in date field, if i selecte date, then it's selected from like `1923` year, i have used rails gem datepicker and configured like `$('.datepicker').datepicker({
 format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',regional: "ja",todayHighlight: true,changeMonth: true,changeYear: true, language: "ja",orientation: "auto",toggleActive: true,constrainInput: true,autoclose: true
});`

Comment: @vvp45 can you please check what value saved in `dob` field. Also check the `dob` param in logs when you select the date. I believe `dob` is a date/datetime field.

Comment: @NitinSrivastava Sir, yes dob type date like `   <%= best_in_place record, :dob, :as => :date, class: 'datepicker1 %>`

Comment: @vvp45 - can you please edit your question with a couple of screenshot. That will help to understand the exact issue.

Comment: @NitinSrivastava Sir, please check i have edited my question with adding images of dates.

Comment: And another one more thing need to do, if current value changed then pass params to controller. how will be it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The text value is not displayed because the helper does not find it in your collection.
If your attribute is a string (as supposed by @nitin-srivastava) you have to pass a string collection.

And, according to this post [Rails 4 Best in place select collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27569811/rails-4-best-in-place-select-collection)
You have to pass a Hash collection this form :

```
{"txt1" => "txt1", "txt2" => "txt2", "txt3" => "txt3"}
```

This works for me.

EDIT :
So you can write this :

```
<%= best_in_place record, :gender, as: :select, collection: {'Male' => 'Male', 'Female' => 'Female', 'Other' => 'Other'} %>
```

If record.gender is equal to 'Male', 'Female', or 'Other' it will be displayed.

Comment: and how can we display current option value, which fetch from model loke current gender of user.

Comment: i already tried this, didn't displayed. current value in select field displayed like `-`

Comment: Even date field doesn't work properly, if i select any date from current month date then displayed like `06/04/1923` it goes like this.